# Converting a string to an int using str.at(x)

Tags: c++, string, int

I'm constructing a line command based chess engine. When a command is given to the engine (as a string), I have a couple of regex expressions run to determine if the command is valid. If it's valid, then the command is passed on to be parsed.

When a command such as `a6a4` is given to the engine in `string input;`, is it valid to use a command like:

`istringstream (input.at(1)) >> originalx;` or:

`istringstream buffer(input.at(1)); buffer >> originalx;`

to convert just the part of the string with the integer into an actual int? I have been trying these methods of conversion, all using `str.at(x)` rather than just `str` and none of them seem to be working.

I know this may seem like a duplicate question because everyone wants to know how to convert an entire string to an int, but what about just a specific part of a string? I did search Google for answers as well but nothing I found was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this may seem like a duplicate question because everyone wants to know how to convert an entire string to an int, but what about just a specific part of a string?

A specific part of a `string` is still a `string`. You can just do `str.substr(1, 1)` and convert that whole *sub*-string to an `int`.

Comment: Thanks. Accept when the time limit ends.